# Error 500 when calling POST api to add user to database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, api, controller

I am trying to add a new record into my database, but when i use `fetch` make my api `post` request, I get `error 500`.

I know there are many questions already asking this, but for some reason I couldn't find any answers that solved my problem.

In my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Employee/Create")]
public int Create([FromBody] LoginModel employee)
{
    employeeRepo.RegisterUser(employee);
    return 1;
}
```

This is what my RegisterUser function looks like:

```
public Void RegisterUser(LoginModel data)
{

     var salt = crypt.CreateSalt(5);
     var hashedPassword = crypt.GenerateHash(data.password, salt);
     TblEmployee employee = new TblEmployee();
     employee.Username = data.username;
     employee.Password = hashedPassword;
     employee.Salt = salt;

     db.TblEmployee.Add(employee);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

where db is an instance of the context `EmployeesContext db = new EmployeesContext();`

I have a LoginModel which looks like this:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I am making the api call in the react front-end

```
 fetch('api/Employee/Create/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password })
        })
```

I get an error 500 when I try to run this.
Anyone can help me out with why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

500 means server error.
So I think your server code throws an exception.
Add a try/catch to your Create or RegisterUser method and log the stacktrace, to see what happens.